# Getting sass to work with grunt

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to get sass working with grunt but there's a few things that aren't very clear, even after reading the documentation.

In my gruntfile I have:

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass']
  },

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
```

My questions is should I create scss or css files inside my styles folder and in my html file, should I link to css or scss files?
Also, if I have a very large amount of style files, should I always include each one of them manually or is there an easier way, like in rails where every file inside the styles folder is added automatically?

**EDIT**

[This is what my project structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83M0I.png), only change I've made from the default yeoman angular app was adding the `random.scss` file that I'm trying to turn into regular css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config is kind of wrong, mixing compass with sass. Take a look at that config: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#examples

Of course you create sass or scss files that compile to css. That's what sass is for. In your html you include your final compiled css-files. You could use a plugin like [assetpush](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-assetpush) which could generate the html in your files from the compiled css files. A config maybe could look like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    compile: {
      files: {
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
      }
    }
  },
  assetpush: {
    css: {
        files: {
            "path/to/your.html": ["css/*.css"]
        }
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-assetpush');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'assetpush']);
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, my main.css file should contain the compiled code of all other scss files in the same directory?  I just tried your code but my main.css file is still empty... (And I'm not using assetpush yet)

Comment: keep an ey on the path, i added /main/ to show the possibility on how to add more paths and files. you probably just copy/pasted my code and therefore the path ;-)

Comment: I removed `main` and restarted the server but still no change, main.css is still empty. Also, no idea why you were downvoted..

Comment: but main.css is created, thats good so far. can you show us your current directory-structure in your question? especially where your sass-files are located and some examples of that

Comment: Right now I only have an empty yeoman angular-app. The empty main.css file was generated by yeoman itself. I've updated my original post with a screenshot.

Comment: in your screenshot you can see, that the main.css was generated in your project-root. that file should not be empty ;-) of course you should fix the path. i edit my answer

Comment: what does `assetpush` do? The github page wasn't clear to me.